# Add table row programmatically doesn't work correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `form` like that:

```
<form>
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>SVNr</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td contenteditable="true">Jill</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">Smith</td>
            <td class="svnr" contenteditable="true">50</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Remove" onclick="DeleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td contenteditable="true">Eve</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">Jackson</td>
            <td class="svnr" contenteditable="true">94</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Remove" onclick="DeleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

This one works perfectly. Futhermore, I want to add `table rows` to my table `programmatically`.

I do it this way:

```
        count = numberOfRows;
        formular[count] = new Object();

        formular[count]["Firstname"] = document.getElementById("Firstname").value;
        formular[count]["Lastname"] = document.getElementById("Lastname").value;
        formular[count]["SVNr"] = document.getElementById("SVNr").value;

        var table = document.getElementById("table");
        var TR = table.insertRow(count);

        var TD = document.createElement("td");
        TD.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        var TD2 = document.createElement("td");
        TD2.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        var TD3 = document.createElement("td");
        TD3.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        TD3.className = "svnr";
        var TD4 = document.createElement("td");

        var TXT = document.createTextNode(formular[count]["Firstname"]);
        var TXT2 = document.createTextNode(formular[count]["Lastname"]);
        var TXT3 = document.createTextNode(formular[count]["SVNr"]);
        var Input = document.createElement("input");
        Input.type = "submit";
        Input.value = "Remove";
        Input.onclick = "DeleteRow(this);";

        TD.appendChild(TXT);
        TR.appendChild(TD);

        TD2.appendChild(TXT2);
        TR.appendChild(TD2);

        TD3.appendChild(TXT3);
        TR.appendChild(TD3);

        TD4.appendChild(Input);
        TR.appendChild(TD4);

        document.getElementById("Firstname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("Lastname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("SVNr").value = "";
```

Also this code is working well. The only problem is that the `Remove function` doesn't work correctly for the table rows I added programmatically.

My Removing function looks like that:

```
    function DeleteRow(o) {
        var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }
```

This function removes `ALL` programmatically added values if I press the button for one of them. This function works for the 2 entries in the form I didn't add programmatically but as I said, if I press the `Remove button` for one of added entries, it removes all programmatically added rows and not just the chosen one.

Comment: After you've added your two rows programmatically, use the inspector (webkit) or similar DOM viewer to look at the structure.  My guess is it won't be what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, the `onclick` attribute wasn't added and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in something to uniquely identify each tr. You could set a custom attribute on each tr, set a unique id, etc. and pass the unique value to the delete function.

In addition you may find it easier to work with tables by using the DOMTable properties & methods:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/tableproperties.shtml

http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/tablemethods.shtml